# How to test HttpApplication Object with HttpApplicationState

Tags: testing, httpapplication

I am trying to test a 'plugin' for an ASPNET HttpApplication that is loaded on `Application_Start`.

The code is something like this:

```cs
private HttpApplication application;

public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.application = sender as HttpApplication;

    StartReportService();
}

private void StartReportService()
{

    HandledReports = new SortedList<string, string>();
    HandledReports.Add("myindex","myvalue");

}

public System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<String, String> HandledReports
{
    get 
    {
        application.Application.Lock();
        var handledReports = (SortedList<String, String>)application.Application["handledReports"];
        application.Application.UnLock();
        return handledReports;
    }
    set 
    { 
        application.Application.Lock();
        application.Application["handledReports"] = value; 
        application.Application.UnLock();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a good way to test the `HttpApplicationState` mainly because the `HttpApplication.Application` property is not overridable and there does not seem to be a `HttpApplicationBase` class in the `System.Web.Abstractions` that would allow this.

I have tried variations of the following, always running into a road block each time.

```cs
[TestMethod()]
public void StartReportService_ApplicationStateShouldContainMyIndex()
{
    //No HttpApplicationBase in System.Web.Abstractions, must use Real Object
    var application = new Mock<HttpApplication>();

    //Real object does not have a property of type HttpApplicationStateBase so must use real one?
    //var applicationStateBase = new Mock<HttpApplicationStateBase>();

    //real one not creable so HACK get private constructor
    var ctor = typeof(HttpApplicationState).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { }, new ParameterModifier[] { });
    var applicationState = (HttpApplicationState)ctor.Invoke(new Object[] { });

    //fails here, HttpApplication.Application not overridable
    application.SetupProperty(x => x.Application, applicationState);


    var plugin = HttpApplicationPlugin.HttpApplicationPluginInstance;
    plugin.Application_Start(application.Object,null);

    ...evaluate result...
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on some good approaches for me? This is the first test of more that will rely on being able to have a functioning HttpApplicationState mocked.

Answer (score 7):

Well with some careful thought and a bit of reflection :) , I came up with this solution to my own problem to get me going:

```cs
 [TestMethod()]
 public void StartReportService_ApplicationStateShouldContainMyIndex()
 {
    HttpApplicationPlugin plugin=null;
    HttpApplication app = null;
    HttpApplicationState applicationState = null;
    String tempDir = "";
    try
    {
        #region "Create HttpApplication and ApplicationState"

        //No HttpApplicationBase in System.Web.Abstractions, must use Real Object
        app = new HttpApplication();

        //real one not creatable so HACK get private constructor
        var ctor = typeof(HttpApplicationState).GetConstructor(
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                      null, new Type[] { }, new ParameterModifier[] { });
        applicationState = (HttpApplicationState)ctor.Invoke(new Object[] { });

        //HACK in the state prop for testing
        var stateProp = typeof(HttpApplication).GetField(
                           "_state", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        stateProp.SetValue(app, applicationState);

        #endregion


       plugin = HttpApplicationPlugin.HttpApplicationPluginInstance;
       plugin.Application_Start(application.Object,null);
```

Essentially you can use reflection to give you an `HttpApplication` Object with a `HttpApplicationState` object that will suffice for testing code blocks that rely on this.

Comment: Thanks for this you just saved me a load of time trying to do near enough exactly the same thing